# Gson and a comma in the last item of an array

Tags: gson, android

I have this JSON

```
{
  id: 142,
  fields: [
    { fieldId: 50, value: 0 },
    { fieldId: 51, value: 0 },
    { fieldId: 52, value: 0 }, // <--- Notice the comma
  ]
}
```

**As you can see, there is a comma after the last item.**

When I parse with GSON to these objects:

```
class Foo {
    public int id;
    public List<Field> fields;
}

class Field {
    public int fieldId;
    public int value;
}
```

using this code:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Foo foo = gson.fromJson(json, Foo.class);
```

I get a `foo` object **containing 4 items** in the `fields` array.

Is this a problem with GSON or my JSON is not a correctly formatted JSON? I thought that this last comma in JavaScript was permitted...

Comment: Gson also does this with lists. E.g. It will parse `[1,]` as a list of 2 elements consisting of the number `1` followed by a `null` value. Given that the JSON is actually invalid this is almost certainly incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-5) (*Note that I am not sure if this is the latest RFC for JSON*):

> **5.  Arrays**
>
> An array structure is represented as square brackets surrounding
> zero    or more values (or elements).  Elements are separated by
> commas.
>
> array = begin-array [ value *( value-separator value ) ] end-array
>
> There is no requirement that the values in an array be of the same
> type.

Now `GSON` seems to do something like interpreting the last sentence so that `null` is a value. So after your last comma there is a null value.

You can also test what happens if you deserialize the following:

```
{
  id: 142,
  fields: [
    { fieldId: 50, value: 0 },,,,,,
    { fieldId: 51, value: 0 },
  ]
}
```

As you might guess there will be as many `null` objects as there are extra commas.

I would not say that this behavior is a problem nor can I say that it is against RFC.